# Show that (S⊥)⊥=S where S is a subspace of V and V has inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I found some proofs of this that use Hahn–Banach theorem or the closure of a subspace, but those are notions I still didn't learn about so I'm not supposed to use them.

I have proved that $S \subset (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ Basically I did:

Let s in S. $\forall v \in S^{\perp} \implies \langle s,v \rangle = 0 \implies s \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp} \implies S \subset (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$

I don't know how to proceed to prove that $(S^{\perp})^{\perp} \subset S$

Edit: V is a finite-dimensional vector space with inner product.

I appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Of course for this we require that $S$ is closed.  In any case, $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the closed span of $S$, so if you know nothing about closure, you will be out of luck.  If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then all linear subspaces are automatically closed.

Comment: To clarify: Is your vector space finite-dimensional? If so, you should know something about the dimension of $S^\perp$. If not, the result is false as stated.

Comment: @GEdgar yes I forgot to mention that is finite-dimensional, so I guess it's closed even if I don't know what that means yet. So I'll asume S is closed then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $S$ is closed (since otherwise the statement is false)…

If $x \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ write $x=s+s^{\perp}$ where $s \in S$ and $s^{\perp} \in S^{\perp}$. Taking the inner product of both sides with $x$ gives $\lVert x\rVert^2 =\langle s, x\rangle = \lVert s\rVert^2$. Hence $s^{\perp} = 0$ and we get $x = s \in S$.

Comment: Can you do $x=s+s^{\perp}$ if $S$ is not closed?  For this, $s$ should be the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$, which may fail to exist when $S$ is not closed.

Comment: Thanks! V is finite-dimensional so as @GEdgar explained I can assume S is closed. Your proof is very clear, I really appreciate your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I got a different result than the one I accepted,

If $x \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$, write $x=s+s^{\perp}$ where $s \in S$ and $s^{\perp} \in S^{\perp}$.

As $S \subset (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$, then $s \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Then $x-s=s^{\perp} \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

But $s^{\perp} \in S^{\perp}$, so we have $s^{\perp} \in S^{\perp} \cap (S^{\perp})^{\perp} = \{ \vec{0} \} \implies s^{\perp} = \vec{0}$.

So $x = s, \forall x \in (S^{\perp})^{\perp} \implies (S^{\perp})^{\perp} \subset S$.

We already had $S \subset (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$, so we can conclude that $S = (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $v \in S$. What happens with $\langle v, w\rangle$ for any $w \in S^{\perp}$?